# Does Theresa May's government promote any Maidenhead-specific agenda given that she's an MP for that district?

Tags: united-kingdom, theresa-may

Theresa May has been serving as MP for Maidenhead since 1997. Now that she's the Prime Minister, is her government trying to push through any policies that would be of particular benefit for residents of Maidenhead?

Comment: Presumably you mean something beyond policies which are good for the generally traditionally Conservative voting London commuter belt?

Comment: This may be some useful background reading about Maidenhead and May's relation to it: https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/britain-eu-may/

Comment: @origimbo yes, things like new roads, new bridges, new raiilroads, new hospitals, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Theresa May's own website](https://www.tmay.co.uk/issues/local-businesses-and-maidenhead-town-centre), she does:

> Theresa regularly visits local companies across the constituency in order to hear their views on how best to support businesses. She is also strongly supporting efforts to boost Maidenhead town centre. Maidenhead enjoys many advantages – good rail links with London, close proximity to Heathrow Airport, the local waterways, and beautiful surrounding countryside. To ensure that Maidenhead makes the most of these advantages, Theresa is supporting efforts to rejuvenate the town centre.
>
> Theresa regularly meets local businesses, commerce bodies, and the Royal Borough of Windsor & Maidenhead in order to discuss how the town centre can move forward. In particular, she supports the Waterways Development scheme and is backing the Maidenhead Town Centre Area Action Plan (AAP) which has been produced by the Partnership for the Rejuvenation of Maidenhead.

To get an idea of how her constituents view this subject, I recommend The Guardian's documentary on Brexit, specifically [the part where they visit Maidenhead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7E4Kxl7Ei4). Based on that, I'd say her constituents aren't all that convinced, but I don't know to what extent that's representative for May's actions.

Firstly, the documentary is probably not a representative sample of the constituency. Secondly, the constituents may not be fully informed of how what Theresa May actually does for them. For example, good things might happen for the constituency even if Theresa May opposed them or vice versa (good things might not happen for the constituency despite Theresa May making every possible effort). Anyway, I thought the documentary was interesting enough to include.